# How to use intermediate neural network layers for model chaining

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

I have a neural network structured like this:

- *inputs -> neural network layers -> intermediary output -> more layers -> output*

I would like to use the features from the intermediary output for a different downstream task, but I don't want the features to be overfit. When model chaining with other methods I would use k-fold cross validation to solve this problem, however in the case of my neural network there is no requirement for the k- feature vectors to look anything alike, which is a problem for the downstream task. How should I proceed here?

Comment: Why don't you find the regularization parameters (such as weight decay, drop-out etc.) via cross-validation and then re-fit with the selected settings on all data?

Comment: Ideally, you would be able to train the loss against the output and loss against the intermediate task simultaneously. Can you tell us more about what problem you're trying to solve, and how the intermediate representation fits into solving it?

Comment: @Björn this would give me a very good model for the intermediate task, but when I would go to use this model in the next step it would still be over-confident as the model is always a little bit more accurate on data that it has seen compared to data it has not

Comment: @Sycorax that would be ideal but it would make the training datasets intractably large in my scenario as it involves combination of different inputs, which is why I use the intermediate task to extract the relevant features first.